# How to format resource bundle values to be shown in HTML format

Tags: java, resourcebundle

```
key={0}/{1} + {2}/{3}
```

The above value is defined in a resource bundle and is shown as HTML text in the user interface. The above demonstrates adding fractions and I would like to format this in HTML format. Would it be possible to do this in the resource bundle property file itself. If so, how should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly, then you can specify the formating in the resource file. For example add some html tags:

```
key=<i>{0}/{1}</i> + <b>{2}/{3}</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your html code in your resource file. If you're using MessageFormat, quotes should be doubled though.